# When switching tabs removing All Child View Controllers and Move to Parent View Controller IOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am using `tabBarControllers`. I have two tabs (Home and Settings). Setting tab has multiple child view controllers.

What I want is that when I am on a settings child view controller and switch tab back and forth, it will move back to settings parent view controller.

For example: I have 3 settings view controllers (`SettingViewController1`, `SettingViewController2`, `SettingViewController3`), when I am on `SettingViewController3` and switch the tabs (from Settings to Home and back from Home to Settings), it moves to `SettingViewController1` (parent view controller of container).

I hope you understand my question. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by Child View Controllers? Are you using UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a delegate to your `UITabBarController` and in the following method use this code:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    // You can replace the UINavigationController with your Setting's Navigation Controller class.
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) { 
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I think you wrote "Controller class. " by mistake. I just removed it and paste your code and it worked perfectly as I wanted.
Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Naqi Oh yeah, `Controller class.` was on the wrong line, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

with swift 4.2

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        //Setup parent controller in tabbar with remove all chailed controller
        if (viewController is UINavigationController) {
            let navcontrollers = viewController as? UINavigationController
            navcontrollers?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }
```